# What is the difference between threading function and normal function. Does it differ in memory allocation or execution?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, networking, operating-system

Assume I have a function Handle client
def Handle_Client():
        print('Hello StackOverFlow user')

one way to call function handel client using threads
Client_Thread=Thread(target=Handle_Client,args=())

Client_Thread.start()

second way
Client_Thread=Handle_Client()

what is the diff in terms of memory ,execution or is it the same?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of execution,

The first way you mentioned

```
Client_Thread=Thread(target=Handle_Client,args=(1,))
Client_Thread.start()
```

When you create a Thread, you pass it a function and a list containing the arguments to that function. In this case, you’re telling the Thread to run Handle_Client() and to pass it 1 as an argument.

The second way you mentioned is done by creating a class. For instance

```
class Handle_Client(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, i):
  threading.Thread.__init__(self)
self.h = i
def run(self):
  print(“ Value send“, self.h)
Client_Thread = Handle_Client(1)
Client_Thread.start()
```

Here, New class `Handle_Client` inherits the Python `threading.Thread class.`

`__init__(self [,args])`: Override the constructor.

`run()`: This is the section where you can put your logic part.

`start()`: The start() method starts a Python thread.

The Handle_Client class overrides the constructor, so the base class constructor `(Thread.__init__())` must be invoked.

In terms of memory,

In the first method, you run a function as a separate thread, whereas in the second method you have to create a class, but get more functionality. 
That means it would take additional memory since you get more functionality. 
I am not a 100% sure about it but that's what I understood.